# Liferay 6.2: Creating Page programmatically template not applying

Tags: liferay

I have a problem with creating a page programmatically with a page template. The creation of the page is working, but it is not applying the page template to the page. I have searched and found always the same code snippets. There is also no error.

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        long userId = themeDisplay.getUserId();
        long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
        boolean privateLayout = false;
        long parentLayoutId = 0;
        String name = "Testpage";
        String title = null;
        String description = null;
        String type = LayoutConstants.TYPE_PORTLET;
        boolean hidden = false;
        String friendlyURL = "/testpage";
        ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
        serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);
        serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
        Group group = themeDisplay.getScopeGroup();
        serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(group.getGroupId());
        serviceContext.setUserId(themeDisplay.getUserId());
        Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(userId, groupId, privateLayout, parentLayoutId, name, title, description, type, hidden, friendlyURL, serviceContext);

        List<LayoutSetPrototype> lsps = LayoutSetPrototypeServiceUtil.search(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), Boolean.TRUE, null);
        for(LayoutSetPrototype lsp : lsps) {
            System.out.println("->" + lsp.getName() + " - " + lsp.getLayoutSetPrototypeId());
            if (HtmlUtil.escape(lsp.getName()).contains("kDSSMP")){
                System.out.println("hit");
                LayoutTypePortlet ltp = (LayoutTypePortlet) layout.getLayoutType();
                ltp.setLayoutTemplateId(userId, lsp.getUuid(), false);

                LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout.getGroupId(), layout.isPrivateLayout(),layout.getLayoutId(), layout.getTypeSettings());
                addResources(layout, PortletKeys.DOCKBAR);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic question (please correct if I'm in wrong): "hit" is printed and template is not applied?

Just a background question: do you know that LR uses Layout for referring a page and template to indicate a page template? (I think yes)

(If my assertion about "hit" is correct) I don't try your code... but at first look it seems correct.

I have a similar snippet of code (for LR 6.1) in which I wrote:

```
layoutTypePortlet.setLayoutTemplateId(user.getUserId(), layoutTemplate);
LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout);
```

The only differences seem to be on the `setLayoutTemplateId` (but `false` is correct to don't check for permissions) and on `LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout`.

On the last point Javadoc says:

> updateLayout(Layout layout): Updates the layout in the database or adds it if it does not yet exist.

and

> updateLayout(long groupId, boolean privateLayout, long layoutId, String typeSettings): Updates the layout replacing its type settings.

The last note is about `lsp.getUuid()` using... are you sure it is correct?
In javadoc it is declared as "newLayoutTemplateId" and not UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutPrototype instead of LayoutSetPrototype. This is Page Template vs. Site Template.